# 404 issue with ng-include inside of ng-view

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-include, ng-view

I've searched everywhere for the answer but unfortunately I didn't find anything.

I have a working Angular application that looks like this:

```
...
<div class="container" ng-app="myApp">
<div class="page-title">
    <h1>
    Hello
    </h1>
</div>

<div ng-view></div>

</div>
...
```

I'm working with ngRoute to load html partials into the ng-view div.

my JS:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [
    'ngRoute',
    'myControllers'
]);

myApp.config(['$routeProvider', '$httpProvider',
    function($routeProvider, $httpProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
                when('/step1', {
                    templateUrl: 'template1.html',
                    controller: 'Step1Controller'
                }).
                when('/step2', {
                    templateUrl: 'template2.html',
                    controller: 'Step2Controller'
                }).
                when('/step3', {
                    templateUrl: 'template3.html',
                    controller: 'Step3Controller'
                }).
                otherwise({
                    redirectTo: '/step1'
                });
      }]);
```

Up to here, everything works as a charm. I already completed pretty much everything I needed (a multi stepped wizard).

On the last step, I needed to use `<script type="text/ng-template" id="specialTemplate.html"></script>` to generate some special template (a tree)

So, in my last step page partial (template3.html) I did the following:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in [1,2,3]" ng-include="'specialTemplate.html'"></li>
</ul>


<script type="text/ng-template"  id="specialTemplate.html">
 Test
</script>
```

Here I got stuck. I'm getting **404** errors on console (he tries to look up **specialTemplate.html** in the same directory my browser's url points to), and the template does not load.

When I made some tests I saw that if the `ng-include` is outside of the `ng-view`, but inside a clean `ng-controller` separated from my current working flow, It does find and load the template, but this doesn't help me because I must render the tree within my working steps flow.

Is it impossible to load a `<script>` based template inside `ng-view`?

Thanks in advance for your help.

**EDIT:**
Version: AngularJS v1.3.0-beta.3

Comment: AngularJS version? I tried your code in Plunker and it worked fine. Hard to tell if it's related to the environment or not though.

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry, the version is: AngularJS v1.3.0-beta.3

Comment: Don't know right now. Tried in both Plunker and locally in Visual Studo and it worked. Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/ShYX02vIIP2qhMMoNELr?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

it could be that when you try to grab `specialTemplate.html` from within `ngView` it changes the url being pointed to by `ngInclude`. Try hardcoding the path to `specialTemplate.html`. Or you could try putting your `script` inside the `li` because it might also be a scope issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you are testing in a local Windows system, then not serving up your pages from http-server might be the problem.

As a fix, install http-server globally using the commnd:

```
npm install -g http-server
```

and remember to use a sudo for Linux system.
Once the server installed, start the server using the command:

```
http-server
```

Now, go to http://127.0.0.1:8080/ in your browser and navigate to your desired page.